# adjust div and the canvas inside it (with chart.js) to match parent height

Tags: css, html, chart.js

I'm a beginner to CSS and I'm trying to create a page with some tables and charts (using chart.js).
My goal is to have a div filling 100% of the width of the page and inside of it two divs:

1. A div with a table near a chart - 66% of the screen

   1a. Table will be 75% of div

   1b. Chart will take the rest 25% of the div
2. A div with a chart - 33 %

or to make it more visual: something like this:
[image]

The purple is the main div, the blues are the two divs (66% and 33%) inside the main div and the reds (light and dark reds) are the div table and the div contain the 25% chart. The yellows are the canvas for the charts.

In order to get that I wrote something like this (I'm ignoring other style attributes shown in the image [like padding, margin, etc.] for simplicity) :

```
<div id="mainPurple" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="leftBlue" style="width: 66%;">
        <div id="table" style="width: 75%;">
            <table>...</table>
        </div>
        <div id="donutContainer" style="width: 25%; height: 100%;">
            <canvas id="donutChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightBlue" style="width: 33%; height: 100%">
        <canvas id="pie"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like I expected, the purple main div size was determined by the left blue div size that was determined by the table div. What did not happen like I expected is the divs containing the charts, did not stretch to the full height their parent div but instead got this weird ratio:

[image]

The only way I could change the size of the chart divs (like in the first picture) was by setting fixed size to the canvas: `<canvas id="pie" height="300">` (Which is not good enough because I want it to be aligned for every screen. Trying to set the canvas style attribute did not change the canvas at all.

I assume I'm missing something very basic here but even after reading these answers:

[make canvas as wide and as high as parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214873/make-canvas-as-wide-and-as-high-as-parent)

[HTML5 canvas resize to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624268/html5-canvas-resize-to-parent)

I still wasn't able to fix it.

Comment: Yeah ... chartJS has an annoying habit of resizing the canvas as it desires. Try setting `maintainAspectRatio: false`.

Comment: That did make a change but did not solve the problem yet. now it looks like this: http://4.1m.yt/ex7Ns5B.png

Comment: I also tried to set the canvas height to match the table height using JQuery: `var PieCanvas = document.getElementById("pieCanvas"); canvas.height = $("#tableDiv").height();` but it worked only without the chart: http://4.1m.yt/rEqkBVA.jpg

Comment: Have you set `responsive:true`?

Comment: Yes I have. with `responsive:false` I get: http://2.1m.yt/DtbiCAx.png

Comment: @MarkE Is there anything else you think can be done here?

Comment: Short of altering the ChartJS source code there's not much to be done. The auto-sizing of charts is heavily baked into ChartJS. :-// I'm not a ChartJS guru (very occasional user), so maybe someone more familiar with ChartJS "tricks" will come along with an answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, thanks for trying... I'm considering using Chart.js v2.0 which is currently under development. Does anyone had any experience with it?

Comment: Nice, having exactly the same problem and there appears to be no solution. :(

Comment: @kiradotee Yeah... I still wasn't able to solve it in the correct way (I just hard coded the height in pixels for now) but I believe this issue is fixed in Chart.js 2.0 so I would suggest you try it.

Comment: @DMEM tried Chart.js 2.0 as I saw you suggested it before but unfortunately discovered it is not backward compatible. :/ Therefore would have to change quite a lot of code. Oh well. :)

Comment: @kiradotee Yep... Same problem for me...

Comment: You could try using a <div> with padding-bottom:100% and position:relative so the height will match the width. Then place another <div> inside this, position:absolute and top, left, right and bottom all set to 0 so it hugs the outer <div>. Finally place your canvas inside this inner <div>.